# Maintain Directory Structure with Find and SCP

Tags: linux, bash, find, scp

I am using the `find` command to locate files that need to be `scp`'d to a target host. My problem is that the directory structure is not maintained on the target.

`cd /path/to/dir; find . -exec scp -pr {} hostname:/tmp/. \;`

(I have tried this with and with `-r`.)

If `find` yields `./subdir/file`, I would like for it to be copied to `hostname:/tmp/subdir/file`.

Oh, and before it's suggested, the remote host has disabled `rsync`.

Comment: I'm assuming you're passing more options to `find` than you have shown in your question, since you could replace that entire command with `scp -pr /path/to/dir hostname:/tmp/.`

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using `find` to look for very specific files. I did not think my pattern would do more than complicate the example.

Comment: If you have enough disk space you could use `tar` then `scp` the tarball to the remote host then untar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with two separate commands. First you need to create the directories on the remote server where each file is

```
find . -type f -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq | xargs -i ssh hostname mkdir -p /tmp/{}
```

Then you can copy each file as before

```
find . -type f -exec scp {} hostname:/tmp/{} \;
```

Comment: This looks like it should work the best. Thanks. Such a simple problem but it's been giving me a fit. The additional perspective helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need something more complex than just find:

```
#!/bin/bash

remote=user@host:/path/to/dest/

for file in $(find . -type f); do
    echo scp $file ${remote}$(echo $file | sed 's:^\.*/::')
done
```

And you can always condense that down to:

```
for file in $(find . -type f); do echo scp $file user@host:/path/to/dest/$(echo $file | sed 's:^\.*/::'); done
```

Just remove the `echo` when you're sure that it will run as you expect.

Random example output:

```
scp ./cron/test.txt user@host:/path/to/dest/cron/test.txt
scp ./cron/spamproc/rfc822_addresses.php user@host:/path/to/dest/cron/spamproc/rfc822_addresses.php
scp ./cron/spamproc/mime_parser.php user@host:/path/to/dest/cron/spamproc/mime_parser.php
scp ./cron/spamproc/spamproc.php user@host:/path/to/dest/cron/spamproc/spamproc.php
scp ./cron/spamproc/class.imap.php user@host:/path/to/dest/cron/spamproc/class.imap.php
scp ./count_imap.sh user@host:/path/to/dest/count_imap.sh
```

Comment: `scp /path/to/file host:/path/to/file` fails if the directory `/path/to` does not already exist on `host`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Hrmm... well unless you want to re-write a hefty portion of rsync I would suggest getting rsync turned on on the target server.

Comment: Thanks, this could be modified to work if the directory structure is created before hand. Unfortunately, I don't maintain the remote side. Rsync would be better for so many reasons.